# How to get RobotFramework post test results with latest timestamp in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

I am executing robot test results using timestampoutput command to store results , whenever i execute this it will create me a log & report results ending with timestamp . But my problem is how to get the test report/log in jenkins post results which are generated in that timestamp.Please let me know if this is the right approach or any alternate solution is there. Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks

[image]

```
pybot  --outputdir var/test-results/%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2% --timestampoutputs

Output:  var\test-results\20170601\output-20170601-155017.xml
Log:     var\test-results\20170601\log-20170601-155017.html
Report:  var\test-results\20170601\report-20170601-155017.html
```

Answer (score 0):

The date formatting and [Jenkins Robot Framework Publish results](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Robot+Framework+Plugin) plugin are two approaches that conflict each other. The publish result plugin copies the contents of the output folder to a new folder that is in line with the build number. This ensures uniqueness and using the Jenkins UI all the information about when a build was initiated is found, it should not need a folder name based on a date.